# Retrieve existing MongoDB collection after adding inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, migration, mongoid, database

I'm using Mongoid as my DB wrapper. I had a model with no inheritance and thousands of documents in the collection. I then refactored it to inherit from a base class. Now I can't retrieve the original data. I don't see it when querying the class or the base class.

How should I be handling this change? I see that Mongoid does allow inheritance and will store all the documents in the parent collection, then add a "_type" field for type differentiation. Should I migrate the data to a temp collection, deploy the code change and then migrate the temp data to the new base collection and set the _type field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to just do a dump of production to my local db. Then copy the documents to the new base class collection and verify the _type is set. Then finally restore it to production.

Comment: How did you copy the documents to the new base class?

Comment: After you import the collection, check that it has a _type field. If not, you can set it with `db.<collection>.update({ '_type': null }, { $set: { '_type': "<Ruby model class name>" } }, { multi: true });`
Then finally copy them to the new base class collection with: `db.<collection>.copyTo("<parent_collection>");`